# Make a record visible to only a person in a field

Tags: security

I will be making a bunch of new records for a custom object through an import with Data Loader. One of the fields I will be populating will be a lookup field to the User object.

What is the best way to make these records visible to only the person who will be named in that field in that particular record ?

Thank you very much for your feedback.

Comment: How many unique named Users are there for the values for your lookup to the User object? A few? Dozens? A hundred or more? Is this a one-time operation or is it more "permanent?"

Comment: There is potentially hundreds of different users. There will be about a thousand different records being made. Users can be assigned to multiple ones. Essentially I want them to be the "owner" of the record in which they are named in the field. So, they should only see it or edit it.

Comment: You led me to my next question... Who is going to own the records? Does your design allow you to make this User the owner of the record and have the object sharing model as Private?

Comment: The "owner" of the record should be whoever is in the field I am populating with my import. But the custom object I am using doesn't have an Owner field, so I don't know how to make a person the true Owner - with all the Owner capabilities which go along with it. 

Also - even though I said only the "owner" should have access, there will need to be access to management to all of these records as well. So, I don't know if the sharing model can be Private.

Comment: Every sObject record has an OwnerId field on it. Is your custom object the child in a master-detail relationship or is it a stand-alone object?

Comment: It would be a child in a master-detail relationship. Does that mean the Owner of the master record is automatically the Owner of the detail record ? If so, how do I display that if there isn't a standard Owner field available in the detail field ? 

....and how do I make the record only visible to that Owner and another person named in another field ?

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no mention of what your data is or what it's used for, based on your comments in a simple answer:

1. Make your object **not** a detail to a master object so that you can control it's visibility independently from the parent.
2. Set the OWD for this object to Private
3. Create a lookup to the "parent" instead of a master-detail as appropriate
4. Set the OwnerId field on the record to the value of the user that you would have used for the custom field value.

In this scenario, your record's owner can see the record as well as anyone above them in their role hierarchy.